# Can I convert a bit value to display image in a ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET GridView with a column mapped to a boolean. I want do display image instead of True/False.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="980">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Selected">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("is_selected").ToString())=="1" ? "~/images/tick.png" : "~/images/cross.png" %>'   />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3):

just replace `.ToString())=="1"` to `.ToString())==true`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="980">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Selected">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("is_selected").ToString())==true ? "~/images/tick.png" : "~/images/cross.png" %>'   />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you move this parsing logic out to a view model class that resolves the logic and returns the image url in a string property. That way it will be unit testable and much more manageable.

Comment: I have done some changes in code but still am getting error <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetLang((bool)Eval("is_selected")) %>' />  public static string GetLang(bool value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return "../images/cross.png";
        }
        else
            return "../images/tick.png";
    }